# Controller and Route Laravel 4

Tags: layout, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to route my account.blade.php from a folder (providers) but every time I do like this it breaks the layout.

so URL would look like this

```
mywebsite.com/providers/account
```

Route:

```
Route::get('providers/account', array('as' => 'account', 'uses' => 'ProviderController@getLogin' ));
```

Controller:

```
public function getLogin()
{
    return View::make('providers.account')
                    ->with('title', 'Artsgap Account');
}
```

view/providers/account.php:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
        <section class="columns small-12 large-8">
            <h1>Hello Account</h1>
        <section>
</div>          
@stop
```

Comment: 'breaks the layout' how?

Comment: @extends('layouts.default')

well the page is supposed to be laid out using foundation zurb columns. But when my route is like this (Route::get('providers/account') it breaks the coloumns but when its (Route::get('account') it doesn't if that makes sense -.-

Comment: It doesn't. You don't have conditionals nor variables in your blade template. Are you sure the view you're are getting is always the same?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're the same though thing as the other pages just when I put forward slash to make it like

mywebsite.com/providers/account rather than mywebsite.com/account

also the (providers) is a folder inside my app/view

Comment: You have to be sure. Edit it again, put a mark on it and hit both routes again, just to be sure.

Comment: When you link to your CSS file, are you using an absolute or relative link?  (Is the layout failing because you're doing something like ../css/styles.css?)

Comment: Okay thats a very very silly mistake there -.- my css links were like

zurbfoundation/stylesheet/style.css whereas it should be /zurbfoundation/stylesheet/style.css

Comment: I copied my comment to an answer, if you don't mind to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Rename `account.php` to `account.blade.php`.

Answer (score 0):

When you link to your CSS file, are you using an absolute or relative link? (Is the layout failing because you're doing something like ../css/styles.css?)